# Результат запроса на SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных

Какой результат имеет результат данного запроса на SQL?

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(*) FROM Table
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такие варианты ответов:

А) Одна ячейка 
Б) Одна строка
В) Две ячейки
Г) Два столбца, два кортежа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ни один из перечисленных вариантов.

Результатом этого запроса будет ошибка запроса. Потому что вы не можете запрашивать одновременно неагрегированные данные `Name` и агрегирующую функцию `count` без указания собственно группировки - выражения `group by`.

---

Некоторые СУБД могут выполнить такой запрос, каков при этом будет результат - необходимо уточнять в документации этой СУБД.

Comment: Т.е. будет одна строка - с сообщением об ошибке. Это вариант Б.

Comment: @Akina, не согласен. Если посчитать error code, например? Оно тоже в ответе СУБД есть, при том в нормальных условиях отдельно от сообщения.

Comment: Ну да ну да... а если окно клиента ужать до 40 символов, так и вовсе 4 строки выйдет...